# How do I get my divs to ease in right after eachother on page load?

Tags: html, css, animation, fadein, portfolio

I'm making my portfolio and I thought it would be cool when you could see some nice animations when the page loads. only I don't know how to get the animations working. My idea was to make all the classes fade and easeIn slightly after each other so you would get a cool animation sequince when you have loaded the page.

My idea was:
Fade in the title_text in as the first one from left to right.
after that al the programming languages start fading in and ease in to the right from "javascript"  to "php" to "mysql" to "css" and finaly "html".

I would like to make it flexible so that I can add more languages once I have learned them.

I'd like to learn from it myself so that I can make my own animations in the future.

for those interested this is my portfolio
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx3mG.png)

thanks in advance!

```
<div class="animations">
        <div class="html">
            HTML
        </div>
        <div class="css">
            CSS
        </div>
        <div class="php">
            PHP
        </div>
        <div class="javascript">
            JAVASCRIPT
        </div>
        <div class="mysql">
            MySQL
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
span.mycalendar {
  font-size: 0.38em;
  line-height: initial;
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #CFAF3B;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 10%;
  transform-origin: 50% 10%;
}

title_text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-top: -420px;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: league-gothic;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border: 10px solid white;
}

.animations .html {
  font-family: league-gothic;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 200px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  animation: 5s linear 2s infinite alternate;
}

.animations .css {
  font-family: league-gothic;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.animations .php {
  font-family: league-gothic;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  top: -270px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.animations .javascript {
  font-family: league-gothic;
  float: left;
  top: -330px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.animations .mysql {
  font-family: league-gothic;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -500px;
  top: -150px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
}

li {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.mycalendar * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

span.mycalendar strong {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 0.06em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #CFAF3B;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #CFAF3B;
}

span.mycalendar span {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3.7em;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  color: #2f2f2f;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: may the solution be done in jquery?

Comment: For starters you could reduce a lot of your CSS by using "classes" correctly. They are meant to represent shared information about your elements. A super-simplified example might be an "uppercaseWhiteTextClass". You can then have one rule for this that sets `font-family, font-size, color, z-index, position`, and any other attributes common to all these elements. Keep in mind, an element can have any number of classes. Instead, currently all your classes are uniquely-named based on the title content; that's actually closer to how IDs would be used.

Comment: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @Katana314. Classes are better used when the they describe what the content *is* as opposed to how it *looks*. `uppercaseWhiteTextClass` is a poor class name. `subheading` (or something similar) would be much more suitable.

Comment: @Quantastical Yeah, should have mentioned that in my 600 characters - ideally, it would be `languageLink` or similar. I gave that example name initially to express the actual effect it would have, but maybe that was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've scaled it down a bit for the demo but I hope you get the idea

```css
.animations .css,
.animations .html,
.animations .javascript,
.animations .mysql,
.animations .php {
  font-family: league-gothic;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

body {
  background: #777
}

.animations .html {
  animation-delay: 0s
}

.animations .css {
  animation-delay: 1s
}

.animations .php {
  animation-delay: 2s
}

.animations .javascript {
  animation-delay: 3s
}

.animations .mysql {
  animation-delay: 4s
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animations">
  <div class="html">
    HTML
  </div>
  <div class="css">
    CSS
  </div>
  <div class="php">
    PHP
  </div>
  <div class="javascript">
    JAVASCRIPT
  </div>
  <div class="mysql">
    MySQL
  </div>
</div>
```

Or make other weird and wonderful animations

```css
.animations .css,
.animations .html,
.animations .javascript,
.animations .mysql,
.animations .php {
  font-family: league-gothic;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(0,0);
  animation-name: pop-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

body {
  background: #777
}

.animations .html {
  animation-delay: 0s
}

.animations .css {
  animation-delay: 1s
}

.animations .php {
  animation-delay: 2s
}

.animations .javascript {
  animation-delay: 3s
}

.animations .mysql {
  animation-delay: 4s
}

@keyframes pop-in {
  from {
    transform: scale(0,0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animations">
  <div class="html">
    HTML
  </div>
  <div class="css">
    CSS
  </div>
  <div class="php">
    PHP
  </div>
  <div class="javascript">
    JAVASCRIPT
  </div>
  <div class="mysql">
    MySQL
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot. i got your concept, as i see how you did it, it looks not that hard anymore. i will try to fiddle around it myself. the code works like it is supposed to. thanks alot!